# Variable not being set and returning a unusual number

Tags: c++, function, class

I have a function that is being used to calculate the damage caused towards an object

```
string Weapon::attack(int Damage, int ExtraDamage, string Type)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int totalDamage = 0;

    int percentileDie = rand() % 100 + 1;

    if (percentileDie <= ChanceToHit) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= Damage; i++)
        {
            int sixSidedDie = rand() % 6 + 1;
            totalDamage = totalDamage + sixSidedDie;
        }
        totalDamage = totalDamage + ExtraDamage;
    }
    else {
        totalDamage = 0;
    }

    Result = totalDamage;

    if (Type == "Crossbow") {
        return "Twang! ";
    }
    else if (Type == "Dagger" || Type == "Sword") {
        return "Swing! ";
    }

}
```

However, when I go and call the variable `Result` in my program, I get the number `-858993460`. I changed `Result = totalDamage` to `Result = 6` to see if it would return `6` but it once again returned `-858993460`.

Can anyone help me out?

If I do this:

```
Weapon t;
t.attack(2, 4, "Sword");
cout << t.attack(2, 4, "Sword") << t.Result << endl;
```

I get the correct number, but if I do this:

```
Weapon t;
cout << t.attack(2, 4, "Sword") << t.Result << endl;
```

I get the number `-858993460` again!

Also, Result is declared in a class:

```
class Weapon {
public:
    string Name;
    int Damage, ExtraDamage, Result;
    float ChanceToHit;

    string attack(int,int,string);
};
```

Comment: Can `Type` can be something other than "Crossbow", "Dagger", or "Sword"?

Comment: That's not the relevant code. Show more.

Comment: Please edit your question, and post a [mcve].

Comment: post the real code, this won't compile, `Result` is not declared anywhere.

Comment: Show us the declaration of `Result`.

Answer (score 4):

The order of evaluation of `cout << X << Y` is not ordered for `X` and `Y`.

So this code:

```
Weapon t;
cout << t.attack(2, 4, "Sword") << t.Result << endl;
```

will evaluate either `t.attack()` or `t.Result` first - based on your post, it would seem that `t.Result` is evaluated first.

The solution is to force the compiler to do things in the correct order, e.g.

```
Weapon t;
std::string str = t.attack(2, 4, "Sword");
cout << str << t.Result << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look into what exactly is going on here, then you will realize that operator "<<" is being used to add data to output stream.
The "<<" operator is defined to add data on stream and return a reference of modified stream for further use, this is the reason we can use multiple "<<" in single "cout" So the order of putting values on stream is reverse of the order in which you read it.

So it is like

```
cout<<firstOperand<<secondOperand<<thirdOperand;
```

is evaluated as

```
cout(<<firstOperand(<<secondOperand(<<thirdOperand)));
```

Which in turn means that "thirdOperand" is added to output stream first then updated stream is returned. Now "secondOperand" is pushed to the same returned stream similarly and then "firstOperand" is pushed to the output stream. Now all "<<" operators are done. Now cout puts the stream content on the output file.

So, in your case, because t.Result is getting added to output stream before its calculation in class function, the value that you get is random value of Result initialized during object construction.